# Twitter json data in Hadoop

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive

I Have done Twitter data streaming into HDFS. This is my Twitter-agent configuration:

```html
#setting properties of agent
Twitter-agent.sources=source1
Twitter-agent.channels=channel1
Twitter-agent.sinks=sink1

#configuring sources
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.type=com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.channels=channel1
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.consumerKey=<consumer-key>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.consumerSecret=<consumer-secret>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.accessToken=<access-token>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.accessTokenSecret=<Access-Token-secret>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.keywords= morning, night, hadoop, bigdata

#configuring channels
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.type=memory
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.capacity=10000
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity=100

#configuring sinks
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.channel=channel1
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.type=hdfs
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path=flume/tweets
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.rollSize=0
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.rollCount=10000
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.batchSize=1000
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.fileType=DataStream
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.writeFormat=Text
```

Twitter Data is streamed successfully. But every FlumeData file in HDFS  is like this:

```html
SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable� ���^�kd��h?�tN ���h{"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Tue Jun 23 15:09:32 +0000 2015","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"source":"<a href=\"http://tweetlogix.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Tweetlogix<\/a>","retweet_count":0,"retweeted":false,"geo":null,"filter_level":"low","in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"id_str":"613363262709723139","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"favorite_count":0,"id":613363262709723139,"text":"Morning.","place":null,"lang":"en","favorited":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"coordinates":null,"truncated":false,"timestamp_ms":"1435072172225","entities":{"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[],"trends":[],"symbols":[]},"contributors":null,"user":{"utc_offset":-14400,"friends_count":195,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/613121771093532673/mA5NPv6X_normal.jpg","listed_count":16,"profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000045222063/847094549362b20f2b1e3c1ff137a80f.png","default_profile_image":false,"favourites_count":891,"description":"See, I was actually on my way to get a piece of burger from Burger King.....","created_at":"Sat Apr 30 00:51:06 +0000 2011","is_translator":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000045222063/847094549362b20f2b1e3c1ff137a80f.png","protected":false,"screen_name":"NilesDontCurrr","id_str":"290266873","profile_link_color":"FF0000","id":290266873,"geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"FFFFFF","lang":"en","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_text_color":"34AA7A","verified":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/613121771093532673/mA5NPv6X_normal.jpg","time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","url":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_background_tile":true,"profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/290266873/1432844093","statuses_count":68154,"follow_request_sent":null,"followers_count":4611,"profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"following":null,"name":"niles.","location":"New York City.","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"AFDFB7","notifications":null}}
```

When I parse this json data in Hive I'm getting errors like

```html
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('S' (code 83)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5fdcaa40; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I think the error is because of this line which is the first line in every FlumeData File.  `SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable�  ���^�kd��h?�tN ���h` Am I right?

Isn't the twitter json data supposed to start like this `{"in_reply_to_status_id_str":......}` ?

Comment: Its not just the start of json. Please verify the rest of the data too, and why this error "Unexpected character ('S' (code 83))"

Comment: I have included one entire FlumeData file, please do have a look. I think the error is because of the first line which is starting with "SEQ"

Comment: This is not a json file, this is a sequence file with JSON in it, encoded as a byte array.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut good observation. I did not notice it. May be the S is coming from SEQ, in the error. May be we need to get hold of seq file and extract json and then give to Hive.

Comment: @Ramzy How can we do that?

Comment: A SequenceFile is a flat file consisting of binary key/value pairs.You can use help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798060/convert-sequence-file-and-get-key-value-pairs-via-map-and-reduce-tasks-in-hadoo). At high level, the idea is converting from bytes to actual format(key value) and then get data(your json) from there. Once you know the conversion, you can depend on map reduce to perform the task of loading and formatting as per your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flume is generating files in binary format instead of text format. This is because few of the properties in your config file are not set correctly, including below two properties.

```
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.fileType=DataStream
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.writeFormat=Text
```

Correct way to set properties is as below.

```
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text
```